# Error: Failed to find request token in session while trying to access Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, passport.js

Whenever I try to connect to Twitter API using Passport OAuth, I have this issue that prevents me to and redirects me to an error page that displays this message:

```
Error: Failed to find request token in session
at SessionStore.get (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/requesttoken/session.js:13:44)
at OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:214:33)
at attempt (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
at authenticate (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at cors (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
at /Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
at originCallback (/Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
at /Users/youcefchergui/Work/ESP/socialboard/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
```

I tried to search for an answer but all the solutions I found on the internet weren't efficient.

I tried to set the cookies mode to secure

```
app.use(session({
genid: function(req) {
    return null; // use UUIDs for session IDs
},
secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
maxAge: 86400000,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: {
    secure: 'auto'
}
```

}));

I also tried to set the callbackUrl from

> localhost

to

> 127.0.0.1

but Twitter Portal prevents me to do so by telling me that the callbackUrls don't match.

(I've tried all the combinations possible: localhost in Twitter Portal, 127.0.0.1 in my code, reverse too and also both localhost or 127.0.0.1 in both Portal and code)

I also tried to switch from TwitterOauthStrategy to OAuth1Strategy but wasn't successful.

Thanks for your help, I'm desesperate.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically this issue/error you get is because for Twitter API you must use `callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"` in yourApp.js file and also in your Twitter Dev Account at `Callback URI / Redirect URL` you should have `http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback` set as well.

Now in your browser you should **always access** under `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, if you try `http://localhost:3000/` you'll get this error every time `Error: Failed to find request token in session`.

I also used **FacebookStrategy**, **GoogleStrategy** and these work fine in both ways `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and `http://localhost:3000/`.

Here is my session code and it works for all 3 strategies FacebookStrategy, GoogleStrategy, TwitterStrategy:

```
    app.use(
        session({
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            maxAge: 86400000,
            cookie: {},
        })
    );
```